# Joint cdf and marginal cdf (please help)

Tags: probability

Suppose X and Y have a joint pdf
$$
f(x,y) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc} 8xy ~&\text{if}~ 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 &~\text{ otherwise} \end{array}
\right. 
$$
What is the Joint CDF and marginal CDF?

I tried to find it (the answer that I got for joint CDF 2x^2y^2) but I’m not really sure. Also can someone please tell me how to draw the region and decide the limit of integration that we have to use?

Answer (score 2):

Call $f_X(x)$ the marginal of X.

$f_X(x)=\int_0^1f(x,y)dy=\int_x^1 8xydy = 4(1-x^2)$

*Explanation attempt:*

You need to integrate with respect to all other variables. The reason is the following:

In order to give you better intuition on this integral (hopefully) I use the relationship between the cumulative distribution function $F$ and the density $f$.

$F(X,Y) = P(X<x,Y<y) = \int_{-\infty}^{y}  \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x,y)dx dy$

Therefore,

$F_X(x) = P(X<x) = P(X<x, Y<+\infty)  = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x,y)dx dy$

$f(x) = \dfrac{dF_X(x)}{dx} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  f(x,y)dy$